# What is a faster way to manipulate one column in a data.frame row by row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with numeric latitude and longitude values. The data.frame has 14K rows and 40 columns.

I'd like to add a category column called "hemisphere" to the data frame in order to easily distinguish between northern (latitude > 0) and southern locations (latitude < 0). This is what I do:

```
for (r in 1:nrow(myDataFrame)) {
  if (myDataFrame[r, "latitude"] > 0) {
    myDataFrame[r, "hemisphere"] <- "North"
  } else {
    myDataFrame[r, "hemisphere"] <- "South"
  }
}
```

Running this code block takes about a minute, maybe two, on my MacBook Pro - much longer than I'd expect. It seems as if something makes it very inefficient and there should be a better way. Any hints?

Comment: how about `myDataFrame = transform(myDataFrame, hemisphere = ifelse(latitude > 0, "North", "South"))`?

Comment: @baptiste Yep, that's really fast. Thanks! Why not make it a real answer?

Answer (score 4):

@baptiste's `ifelse` solution is the general idiom for speeding up comparisons with vectorisation, but in this case, some judicious subsetting and the use of `sign` might be faster:

```
myDataFrame$hemisphere <- c("South","Equator","North")[sign(myDataFrame$latitude)+2]
```

Answer (score 3):

`ifelse` is quick but if efficiency is required you might be better off with subsetting-base approaches.

Given some example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(site = 1:14000, latitude = rnorm(14000))
```

My version of the sort of thing @James does in his Answer is just to compare `latitude > 0` which returns a logical vector and add `1` to this (so we have a numeric vector of `1`s and `2`s. Then use that to index into the vector of possibilities `c("South","North")`.

```
df$hemisphere <- c("South","North")[(df$latitude > 0 ) + 1]
```

Which gives

```
> head(df)
  site   latitude hemisphere
1    1 -0.6264538      South
2    2  0.1836433      North
3    3 -0.8356286      South
4    4  1.5952808      North
5    5  0.3295078      North
6    6 -0.8204684      South
```

Comment: @James Thanks for that. Quite embarrassing, what with my being a Geographer and all. Brain fail there. Fixed now.

Comment: Lets say it was a geomagnetic reversal

Comment: @James I studied those as an undergraduate some moons ago now (my particular branch of Geography is more aligned with geology as I now research past environmental/global change.) I should have invoked that reason so I didn't look like an incompetent idiot ;-)