# R factor with two types as numeric

Tags: r, numeric, levels

I have a factor with 49 levels in R which I am trying to convert to a number using as.numeric

- Latitude: Factor "0.80N", "0.40S", ...

I am looking to convert the North designation to "+" and the South to "-" so that the data looks like

- Latitude: num  0.80, -0.40, ...

I'm not sure how to go about doing so beyond

```
Mcity$lat <- as.numeric(Mcity$Latitude)



structure(c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), .Label = 
  c("0.80N", "0.80S", "10.45N", "12.05N", "12.05S", "13.66N", "13.66S",
    "15.27N", "15.27S", "16.87N", "18.48N", "18.48S", "2.41N", "20.09N", 
    "20.09S", "21.70N", "23.31N", "23.31S", "24.92N", "26.52N", "28.13N", 
    "29.74N", "29.74S", "31.35N", "32.95N", "32.95S", "34.56N", "34.56S", 
    "36.17N", "37.78N", "37.78S", "39.38N", "4.02N", "4.02S", "40.99N", "42.59N", 
    "44.20N", "45.81N", "49.03N", "5.63N", "5.63S", "50.63N", "52.24N", "55.45N", 
    "60.27N", "7.23N", "7.23S", "8.84N", "8.84S"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: something like this?

> dput(head(Mcity$Latitude,4))

Comment: structure(c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), .Label = c("0.80N", "0.80S", 
"10.45N", "12.05N", "12.05S", "13.66N", "13.66S", "15.27N", "15.27S", 
"16.87N", "18.48N", "18.48S", "2.41N", "20.09N", "20.09S", "21.70N", 
"23.31N", "23.31S", "24.92N", "26.52N", "28.13N", "29.74N", "29.74S", 
"31.35N", "32.95N", "32.95S", "34.56N", "34.56S", "36.17N", "37.78N", 
"37.78S", "39.38N", "4.02N", "4.02S", "40.99N", "42.59N", "44.20N", 
"45.81N", "49.03N", "5.63N", "5.63S", "50.63N", "52.24N", "55.45N", 
"60.27N", "7.23N", "7.23S", "8.84N", "8.84S"), class = "factor")

Comment: I _really_ think this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359115/converting-latitude-and-longitude but if I mark it that way w/o confirmation it will close the q and I'm not sure that's warranted due to the slightly different input format.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, it is certainly *very* close. You could argue that if someone looked up that question they could easily adapt. The only difference is splitting the string into pieces... but again, there are many questions addressing that too.

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
Mcity$lat <- (1 - 2 * grepl("S", Mcity$Latitude)) * as.numeric(gsub("N|S", "", Mcity$Latitude))
```

if it finds an S it changes the sign of the numeric part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stringr` to chop the last character and then `dplyr` as an option to recombine, I've used `case_when` to provide extra error handling, but an `ifelse` would have been sufficient.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

fct_list <- factor(
  c(
    "0.80N", "0.80S", "10.45N", "12.05N", "12.05S", "13.66N", "13.66S",
    "15.27N", "15.27S", "16.87N", "18.48N", "18.48S", "2.41N", "20.09N",
    "20.09S", "21.70N", "23.31N", "23.31S", "24.92N", "26.52N", "28.13N",
    "29.74N", "29.74S", "31.35N", "32.95N", "32.95S", "34.56N", "34.56S",
    "36.17N", "37.78N", "37.78S", "39.38N", "4.02N", "4.02S", "40.99N",
    "42.59N", "44.20N", "45.81N", "49.03N", "5.63N", "5.63S", "50.63N",
    "52.24N", "55.45N", "60.27N", "7.23N", "7.23S"
  )
)

# note that factors are often no fun, so I've converted to character here
string <- as.character(fct_list)

case_when(
  str_sub(string, -1, -1) == "N" ~ as.numeric(str_sub(string, 1, nchar(string) - 1)),
  str_sub(string, -1, -1) == "S" ~ -as.numeric(str_sub(string, 1, nchar(string) - 1)),
  TRUE ~ NA_real_
)

#  [1]   0.80  -0.80  10.45  12.05 -12.05  13.66 -13.66  15.27
#  [9] -15.27  16.87  18.48 -18.48   2.41  20.09 -20.09  21.70
# [17]  23.31 -23.31  24.92  26.52  28.13  29.74 -29.74  31.35
# [25]  32.95 -32.95  34.56 -34.56  36.17  37.78 -37.78  39.38
# [33]   4.02  -4.02  40.99  42.59  44.20  45.81  49.03   5.63
# [41]  -5.63  50.63  52.24  55.45  60.27   7.23  -7.23
```

Far more verbose than the regex solution from *BenoitLondon* but I tend to lean towards legibility over being concise during exploratory work.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative with ifelse could be the following:

```
lat <- c("0.80N", "0.80S", "10.45N", "12.05S", "12.05S")
lat <- as.character(lat)
## use of substr function inside an ifelse function
lat2 <- ifelse(substr(lat,nchar(lat),nchar(lat)) == 'N',
              as.numeric(substr(lat,1,(nchar(lat)-1))),
              -as.numeric(substr(lat,1,(nchar(lat)-1))))
```

Comment: what is it that your answer adds that does not exist in the other solutions?

Comment: First, when I went through it, there was only one answer. In contrast with the first answer, mine does not need to  search regular expressions. so it is easier to understand for someone that is looking for help, and obviously doesn't master regular expressions. I am using simple and widely used functions: *ifelse* and *substr*.
Also, it is much neater and simpler than your answer, that depends on third party packages like *dplyr* and *stringr*.